# How to create dynamic tabs and load different products to each fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragment, android-tablayout

[image]

Please See the pic for example
It having categories in tabs and products in fragment's listview
when swipe or click on categories is load products in same fragment.

What is want is - 
I want to create an eCommerce app.Which having categories and products in categories.
I want to show Categories in Tabs and Load product in a fragment. all data comes from two web-services. One for Categories and One for Product.
Well
When I click or swipe to other categories, List-view items(Products) will load in One Fragment according to categories.
I have No code right now.
if anyone helps me, please.

Tabs - Categories

Fragment(Listview) - Products

Answer (score 2):

You can use TabLayout to create upper tab, further, you can create the dynamic tab by doing this :

```
   for(i=0; i <mYourLength;i++) {
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Xyz"));
   }
```

And to update each fragment, this thing you can do in PagerAdaptor.